# text box value not passing to the api call

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

I followed the below link and tried to do a poc https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/82mxz3/how_to_make_an_api_call_on_props_change

In Searchbar I created a textbox, and I am getting the value but in index.js when I give componentWillRecieveProps and print the values to pass it to the api but nothing printing. Can you tell me how to fix it.Providing updated code sandbox and code snippet below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-galielo-14874

```
//import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { Fragment, useState, Component } from "react";

import "./styles.css";



class SearchBar extends Component {
  state = {
    groupCheckBoxValues: [],
    groupRadioValue: "PRO"
  };

  getInitialState() {
    return { value: "Hello!" };
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    console.log("handleChange", event.target.value);

    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps({ search }) {
    console.log(search);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchdata("story");
  }

  fetchdata(type = "", search_tag = "") {
    var url = "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?tags=";
    fetch(`${url}${type}&query=${search_tag}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.props.getData(data.hits);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually passing the text input's value to the fetch request.

I recommend something like this:

```
class SearchBar extends Component {

  searchByKeyword = ({target}) => {
    await this.getQuery("story", target.value)
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getQuery("story", "butts");
  }

  getQuery = async(type = "", search_tag = "") => {
    var url = "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?tags=";
    const resp = await fetch(`${url}${type}&query=${search_tag}`)
    return resp.json()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={this.searchByKeyword}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I removed the state and things because it doesn't seem entirely germane to the question.

Comment: hi, can you let me know how to implement using componentwillReceiveProps , Like they mentioned in this article https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/82mxz3/how_to_make_an_api_call_on_props_change

Answer (score 0):

There're some mistakes in your demo. 
The function setState function won't work cause you didn't bind it to your component.
The UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps() is unsafe function. It will be deprecated soon.
And you shouldn't use { useState } hook in Class Component. 
I think you should check some tutorials for fetching data from reactjs site. It will provide some good practices for you :)